# How to edit two model classes in a single form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to edit a form which handles two entity classes, `file.java` and `client.java` having the primary key of client, clientId as Client_clientId in file.java. I'm probably doing something wrong in the urls and am in a fix.

This is `file.java`

```
@Entity
public class file {
    @Id
    private int fileNumber;
    private String fileName;
    private String description;
    private String purpose;
    @Transient
    private String assignedAdvocate;
    private String comment;
    private int Client_clientID;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date timestamp;
```

This is `client.java`

```
@Entity
public class client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int clientId;
    @NotNull
    private String clientName;
    private String clientAddress;
    private String contactPerson;
    private int phone;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String bank;
    private String branch;
    private String accountNumber;
```

This is the controller class where I am handling the edits.

```
ManageFiles.java



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/advocatoree/manageFiles")
public class ManageFiles {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchFile")
    public ModelAndView inputFileNumber(ModelAndView model){

        model.setViewName("searchFile");
        return model;
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fileStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewFileStatus(@RequestParam("file_number")int id, ModelAndView model){

        model.setViewName("fileStatus");

        file file = em.find(com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.file.class, id);
        model.addObject("file", file);

        client client = (com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.client)em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM client c WHERE c.clientId =:id")
                .setParameter("id", file.getClient_clientID()).getSingleResult();
        model.addObject("client", client);

        List<deposit> deposits = (List<deposit>)em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM deposit d WHERE d.File_fileNumber =:id")
                .setParameter("id", id).getResultList();


        List<expense> expenses = (List)em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM expense e WHERE e.File_fileNumber =:id")
                .setParameter("id", id).getResultList();

        model.addObject("depositList", deposits);
        model.addObject("expenseList", expenses);

        List<bill> fileBills = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM bill b WHERE b.file_fileNumber =:id")
                .setParameter("id", id).getResultList();

        model.addObject("fileBills", fileBills);

        List<fileStatus> fileStatusList = (List)em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM fileStatus f WHERE f.file_fileNumber =:id").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
        for(fileStatus fs: fileStatusList){
            String s =(String)em.createQuery("SELECT e.name FROM employee e WHERE e.employeeID =:id")
                    .setParameter("id", fs.getEmployee_employeeID()).getSingleResult();
            fs.setEmployeeName(s);
        }
        model.addObject("fileStatusList", fileStatusList);

        List<employee> employeeList = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM employee e WHERE e.employeeID !=0").getResultList();

        model.addObject("employeeList", employeeList);

        List<Integer> employeefiles = em.createQuery("SELECT e.employee_employeeID FROM employeefile e WHERE e.file_fileNumber =:id")
                .setParameter("id", id).getResultList();

        ArrayList<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Integer i: employeefiles){
            employee e = em.find(employee.class, i);
            employeeNames.add(e.getName());
        }

        model.addObject("employeeNames", employeeNames.toString());

        model.addObject("employeeFiles", employeefiles);
        return model;
    }


    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateFileClient/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView modifyFileClientInfo(ModelAndView model, @PathVariable("id")int id){
        model.setViewName("modifyFileClientInfo");
        file file = em.find(com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.file.class, id);
//        client client = em.find(com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.client.class, id);
        client client = (com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.client)em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM client c WHERE c.clientId =:id")
                .setParameter("id", file.getClient_clientID()).getSingleResult();
        int zero=0;
        List<employee> employeeList = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM employee e WHERE e.employeeID >:zero")
                .setParameter("zero", zero).getResultList();
        model.addObject("employeeList", employeeList);
        model.addObject("files", file);
        model.addObject("clients", client);
        return model;
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updatedFileInfo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateFileInfo(@ModelAttribute("")file f, client c,
                                        @PathVariable("id")int id){

        file file = em.find(com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.file.class, id);
        client client = em.find(com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.client.class, id);
//        client client = (com.techflakes.advocatoree.model.client)em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM client c WHERE c.clientId =:id")
//                .setParameter("id", file.getClient_clientID()).getSingleResult();
        file.setFileName(f.getFileName());
        file.setDescription(f.getDescription());
        file.setPurpose(f.getPurpose());
        file.setAssignedAdvocate(f.getAssignedAdvocate());
        file.setComment(f.getComment());
        file.setTimestamp(f.getTimestamp());
        file.setClient_ClientID(c.getClientId());
        client.setClientName(c.getClientName());
        client.setClientAddress(c.getClientAddress());
        client.setContactPerson(c.getContactPerson());
        client.setPhone(c.getPhone());
        client.setEmail(c.getEmail());
        client.setBank(c.getBank());
        client.setBranch(c.getBranch());
        client.setAccountNumber(c.getAccountNumber());
        em.persist(client);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(client);
        em.persist(file);
        return "redirect:/advocatoree/manageFiles/searchFile";
    }

}
```

This is the edit button in `filestatus.jsp`

```
<form action="/advocatoree/manageFiles/updateFileClient/${file.fileNumber}" method="post">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple">Edit Information</button>
                                            </form>
```

and this is the url action in `modifyFileClientInfo.jsp`

```
<form method="post" action="/advocatoree/manageFiles/updatedFileInfo/${clients.clientId}">
```

Once I edit the data and submit them, they're supposed to be persisted in the database and should also show in my page with the edited info. What I see is when I click the edit button, it takes the fileNumber and after I edit and submit the data, the edited info is persisted in that file number which is equal to the clientId of the previous file. If 15 is the clientId of file Number 65, the data is persisted in file number 15.

Please. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your method I found you are saving both file & client IDs, but while persisting you are only persisting the client id. But notice how you are totally okay without persisting the file id. Maybe there is a problem with the forced persisting of the client id. Try without it. It should work.

Again, logically your approach should work. I guess you were not successful to save the values properly. Try to get a print of the saved id values before persisting them and check if you are storing them properly or not.